# Basic script listing directories ([: discover: unexpected operator)

Tags: bash, scripts, directory

I encounter an issue running a basic script listing directories.

```
for item in *
do
   if [ -d $item ]
   then
      echo $item
   fi
done
```

The outcome:

1. lists all system folders
2. returns an error: for.sh: 4: [: discover: unexpected operator
3. lists all my folders, whose names start from a lowercase character

My guess is -d finds some issue with an initial lowercase character?
Can somebody please explain why it happens? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some directories/files may contain spaces in their names, this would cause the error you are getting. So use quotes:

```
for item in *
do
   if [ -d "$item" ]
   then
      echo "$item"
   fi
done
```

if you want them sorted alphabetically use

```
for item in *
do
   if [ -d "$item" ]
   then
      echo "$item"
   fi
done | sort
```

---

As an example of the issue, suppose a file is called `My File`. If you don't use quotes you would get (after bash expansion)

```
if [ -d My File ]
```

so it is like "Test: Is `My` a directory? Do `File`", but `File` is not a valid `test` operator, thus the error.

Comment: I'm careful not to name my files with spaces, as it then problematic to call them in commands. But still, it worked. I still don't know, however, why it lists its own folders first, and mine second.

Comment: @denuviel, What do you mean by _lists its own folders first, and mine second_? Also, there might be some files you don't see, but which are caught by the glob pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I've meant the folders that were automatically assembled during system instalation (Desktop, Documents, Downloads), or automatic installations of applications (Dropbox), and then mine (dosgames), instead of arranging them all together in alphabetical order (Desktop, Documents, dosgames, Downloads, Dropbox), it looks like it runs two separate checks?

Comment: @denuviel: Edit the question to include you need to know this. Use `$( echo "*" | sort )` instead of `*` to achieve the sorting.

Comment: This method doesn't work. I've created another thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/326834/why-does-the-script-list-directories-in-two-turns

Comment: `for item in $( echo "*" | sort ); do`. Here, `echo` outputs the character `*` followed by a newline. `sort` receives this single line as input, and outputs the line in sorted order, which is exactly the same as the input order (it's only one line, so there's really no sorting to do). After that, the shell now replaces the `$(...)` with the result, after stripping off any trailing newlines, so we now have `for item in *; do`. It then does pathname expansion, which means the `*` gets replaced by all the matching filenames, in sorted order.

Comment: @geirha: Right! I've corrected it. It's curious but according to `man ls` the default sort order is by name. Maybe **denuviel**'s `ls` has the option `--group-directories-first` set?

Comment: @edwin It's just the collation order. Compare `LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8; echo *` with `LC_COLLATE=C; echo *`. The latter sorts by ascii value where uppercase letters come before lowercase letters. Same with ls. `LC_COLLATE=C ls` (intentionally without `;` between the assignment and ls)

Comment: @edwin Now it works, thanks! :) While I know piping the command into sort did the job, the idea of including it into the script in this manner escaped me.

Answer (score 0):

The following echoes all dirs in the current dir (but not the dotted ones, e.g. `.git`)

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read Directory; do
    echo "$Directory";
done
```

Comment: It's an excersise, I want to understand this particular structure, not to obtain a certain result.