# Why does the script list directories starting with uppercase first, and all-lowercase second?

Tags: bash, scripts, directory

The thread is an extension of: [Basic script listing directories ([: discover: unexpected operator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326793/basic-script-listing-directories-discover-unexpected-operator)

When I execute the script:

```
for item in *
do
   if [ -d "$item" ]
   then
      echo "$item"
   fi
done
```

It lists the folders that were automatically assembled during system instalation (Desktop, Documents, Downloads), or automatic installations of applications (Dropbox), and then mine (dosgames), instead of arranging them all together in alphabetical order (Desktop, Documents, dosgames, Downloads, Dropbox).

Why does it run two separate checks if it's checking for a common characteristic (-d)?

The output:

```
Dokumenty
Dropbox
Muzyka
Obrazy
Pobrane
Publiczny
Pulpit
Szablony
Wideo
dosgames
learning_linux
new
tset
```

I use the Polish version, hence the names of the directories. These however are all default system directories, if not obviously not (ie. Dropbox, dosgames)

Comment: Instead of `for item in *` write `for item in $( echo "*" | sort )`.

Comment: Instead of  `if [ -d $item ]` write `if [ -d "$item" ]` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: The sorting at this stage has no impact on the execution of the code, it still prints the directories in two batches.

Comment: Please add the output of the commands to your question. I don't really understand what you mean by "two batches".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell sorts them according to the [locale](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/locale) you've set. In particular it's the `LC_COLLATE` variable that controls how strings are sorted. In your case, it sorts uppercase characters before lowercase characters like in the `POSIX` or `C` locale (i.e. sorted by the ascii values of the characters).

```
$ mkdir Dokumenty dosgames Dropbox Muzyka learning_linux
$ LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf-8; echo */
Dokumenty/ dosgames/ Dropbox/ learning_linux/ Muzyka/
$ LC_COLLATE=C; echo */
Dokumenty/ Dropbox/ Muzyka/ dosgames/ learning_linux/
```